# gupshup how to store objects to Firebase from Gupshup Bot Builder IDE

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, chatbot, gupshup

I want to store the contextobj to Firebase for later use.
Which I will be using to broadcast the messages to the bot subscribers.
I am not getting how to write to Firebase from Gupshup.IO IDE
If not possible in Firebase which database can be used to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gupshup supports [making HTTP](https://web.archive.org/web/20161007144712/http://www.gupshup.io:80/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/adding-http-calls) calls from the IDE.

So, you can use the **POST** method of Firebase to write contextobj into the Firebase database. Then you can use **GET** method to retrieve contextobj from Firebase and use it. Check out Firebase documentation on [saving](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data) and [retrieving](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data) data.

**OR**

Since, you are using Gupshup.io's IDE then you can directly use the **hosted DynamoDB** which comes with the IDE.

Store all the contextobj into the hosted DB and they you can access it to broadcast the messages to the bot subscribers.

Check out these two documents to understand how to use the hosted DB using the IDE -

1. [Basic data persistence](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/adding-basic-data-persistence)
2. [Advance data persistence](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/adding-advanced-persistence)

Also,check out the second half of this [document](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/http-call-to-a-bot) to understand how you can use the stored contextobj to send out a message to the user.

I will recommend using the Gupshup.io's hosted database to store the contextobj.